# Allow users to revoke a token with Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

Rails 5.2.0, Doorkeeper 5.0.0 RC1, Devise 4.4.3.

I've plugged Doorkeeper into an existing Rails application which uses Devise for user authentication. The goal is to be able to authenticate a particular application (for example, a mobile app) for multiple users and allow a user to have multiple authenticated instances of the application (e.g. for multiple devices) but allow those users to individually revoke access to a single instance of the application.

There'd be a single instance of Doorkeeper::Application, then the [Authorization Code Flow process](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Authorization-Code-Flow) would be followed each time the user wanted to authenticate an application. In config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb, I've got

```
Doorkeeper.configure do 
  resource_owner_authenticator do
    current_user || warden.authenticate!(scope: :user)
  end
end
```

So if the user's logged in they go straight to the "Authorization required" view (as in the wiki page; I haven't customised that yet) but otherwise the user's first asked to log in, a code is returned and that can be exchanged for an access token and a refresh token. So far, so good.

When it comes to revoking the token, however, I'm having the same problem as [Revoking token does not work for public clients #891](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/891). I want to call /oauth/revoke with the token and have it revoked, without using the application secret or revoking the application (either globally or all instances for the user).

However, this doesn't work for a similar reason as in the GitHub issue - because the tokens controller doesn't check resource_owner_authenticator it can't know if the request to revoke the token is from the resource owner, so authorized? returns false and nothing happens.

As an alternative, I've hacked this together - it's not complete (for one, it'll never send a response) but does this approach make sense?

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
def revoke_oauth_token
  token_string = params[:token]

  unless current_user.nil?
    unless token_string.nil?
      token = Doorkeeper::AccessToken.find_by("resource_owner_id = ? AND token = ?", current_user.id, token_string)

      unless token.nil?
        token.revoke
      else
        # current_user doesn't own the token or the token doesn't exist
      end
    end
  else
    # should be redirected to the login page because of authenticate_user
    # but just in case
  end
end
```

I'd pass in the token, confirm that there's a logged in user and that they're the resource owner of the token, then revoke the token if that all succeeds. It seems to do what I'm looking for but I'm not familiar enough with OAuth in general or Doorkeeper in particular to be sure that I'm not missing something.